# Meteor Admin User not accessing all users collection

Tags: reactjs, meteor

I have added roles to my user collections. I'm trying to publish all users collection to admin user only but I'm only getting admin collection being returned currently.

`Publish code:`

```
Meteor.publish("users", function() {
    let result = [];
    if (Roles.userIsInRole(this.userId, ["admin"])) {
      result = Meteor.users.find({});
    } else {
      this.stop();
    }
    return result;
  });
```

`Subscription`

```
Meteor.subscribe("users");
```

Adding admin:

```
 if (!Meteor.users.find().count()) {
    var users = [
      { name: "Johnson Doe", email: "admin@example.com", roles: ["admin"] }
    ];

    _.each(users, function(user) {
      var id;

      id = Accounts.createUser({
        email: user.email,
        password: "password@123",
        profile: { name: user.name }
      });

      if (user.roles.length > 0) {
        Roles.addUsersToRoles(id, user.roles, "default-group");
      }
    });
  }
```

Is there a way that the admin user can have access to all other user collections?

Comment: Please add the code of `Roles.addUserToRoles` and the publication of your admin collection.

Comment: I'm adding Roles like this:
`Roles.addUsersToRoles(id, user.roles, "default-group");`
And I'm subscribe like this:
`Meteor.subscribe("users");`
`Meteor.users.find().fetch()`

Comment: So when you add "default-group" to Roles.userIsInRole, does it work then?

Comment: I did this on the server side but it's still returning only the current user and not all the users:

     if (Roles.userIsInRole(this.userId, ["admin"], group)) {
          return Meteor.users.find({ group: group }, { fields: { profile: 1 } });
   } else {
      this.stop();
      return;
    }

My goal is for this admin user to read all other users doc.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `addUsersToRoles` make sure it has you admin collection, before declaring `userIsInRole` as like

```
Roles.addUsersToRoles(userId, ['admin']);
```

You can check carefully this [**Usage Examples**](https://atmospherejs.com/alanning/roles#usage-examples)